# CollectionViewCell not displaying cells or loading core data string

Tags: swift, core-data, fetch, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to save a core data string via the first class, then load that string into a collectionviewcell textlabel. I am doing all of this without the use of any storyboards. I am not getting any compile errors. It is just when I load this class, nothing is appearing.

This is a link to my git profile https://github.com/redrock34/collectionViewCellLoad.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var itemsName: [Item] = []
    weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.topAnchor),
            self.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor),
            self.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.leadingAnchor),
            self.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.trailingAnchor),
            ])
        self.collectionView = collectionView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Cell.identifier)
        self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = .brown

        collectionView.reloadData()

    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.itemsName.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Cell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! Cell

        let user = itemsName[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = ("\nCourse: \(user.atBATS!) Score: ")
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            return cell

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty dataSource

```
var itemsName: [Item] = []
```

Comment: How do I feel the dataSource? What do I feel it with?

Comment: fill it with the data you need to show !!?? it appears it's a coredata object so see what you need to do with it

Comment: I am trying to load a string named atBATS, Where would I put that?